# Navigation Drawer Image Size

Tags: android, image, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer that has a similar appearance to the material guidelines. I've been having trouble with sizing, I found out by using the overlay lines that show the views. What's happening in mine is that the image doesn't fill the space to the top of the screen, and to the list that I have below it. Here is a before image showing the top of my titlebar and the status bar, and below is an image of the drawer extended out.
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmaQz.jpg)

I don't have any margins or padding on the imageview itself, or on the drawer. My image size is 320x160, and its in the drawable folder. The image is bigger to fit the tablet width of the nav bar. The width of the phone nav bar is 280dp. It actually shows just fine on the tablet display. Here is the code for it:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navDrawerImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/navimage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into to this problem and solved by specifying the height of the image. You may need to play around with it but 140dp worked for me and leaving the width at fill parent.

Here my code:

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/navdrawerimage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

Hope this helps man!